# ToolTip text as selected value in ASP.Net dropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, tooltip

I have ASP.NET dropdown which is too small to display full text the user had selected.
So i decided to display selected text in tooltip.

```
ApplyToDropDown.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "ShowApplyToText()");

function ShowApplyToText()
{
    var ApplyToDropDown = document.getElementById("ApplyToDropDown"); 
    if(ApplyToDropDown != null)
          ApplyToDropDown.ToolTip = ApplyToDropDown.selectedText; // line 5
}
```

But i am not getting an output.I also tried  ApplyToDropDown.title it also didn't work.

Please help me on this.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/903935/994720.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolTip` is not a valid attribute of a dropdown element (or its option elements) so unfortunately your script won't work. The attribute you want to use is `title`, but unfortunately that will only work on the top dropdown element and not on each option element as you are looking for.

The only way to get this to work would be with some javascript/css trickery where you would hover a div with the tooltip in it next to the dropdown, but there's nothing unfortunately that's built-in that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the title attribute, then it will work in browsers other than IE.

The drop down list renders as a select element in HTML, which is why it doesn't typically have a tooltip.

Have a read of [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/903935/994720.aspx) forum topic.

Comment: Thanks for u'r Response but i am using IE only.